# Can differing collation or character_set values affect query optimizer use of indexes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 10.3.28.  I'm joining 4 tables.

1. Query optimizer correctly uses index for 3 of the tables and scans the main table, table #1.  Query runs in 6 seconds.
2. I swap in a newer version of table #1 with a few added columns, none of which are used in the query, and a few columns renamed.  Now my query only uses the index on the 4th table, resulting horrible performance.  Query takes 63 minutes!
3. I compare the tables and note that older table is using `latin1` character_set and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.
4. Newer table is using `utf8` character_set and `utf8_general_ci` collation.

Is there any chance the key field in the join from table #1, which is a varchar(20), is not getting optimized to use indexes with the newer table #1 as a result of that differing character_set and collation?  The other 3 tables use the same settings as the older table #1 (`latin1`, `latin1_swedish_ci`).

Here are the 2 EXPLAINed queries.
Old table #1:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT
    h.dataareaid,
    h.warehouseid,
    h.itemno,
    h.qoh,
    p.eau,
    h.fifo_cost,
    (h.qoh * h.fifo_cost) AS value,
    ((p.cuft_inner / p.pcs_inner) * h.qoh) AS cuft,
    p.status,
    CASE WHEN (p.status = 'P'
        OR p.isprivatelabel = 1
        OR p.sales_category_id = 7
        OR ph.smoothie_enabled != 1
        OR pe.firstsold > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        OR p.added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        GREATEST(h.qty_avail - p.sold - p.allocated_qty - p.eau, 0)
    END AS excess_qty,
    CASE WHEN (p.status = 'P'
        OR p.isprivatelabel = 1
        OR p.sales_category_id = 7
        OR ph.smoothie_enabled != 1
        OR pe.firstsold > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        OR p.added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        GREATEST((h.qty_avail - p.sold - p.allocated_qty - p.eau) * h.fifo_cost, 0)
    END AS excess_value
FROM
    fiat.parts_warehouse_items h
    LEFT JOIN fiat.parts p ON p.itemno = h.itemno
    LEFT JOIN fiat.parts_ext pe ON pe.itemno = h.itemno
    LEFT JOIN internal.parts_history ph ON ph.itemno = h.itemno
        AND ph.date = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE
    h.warehouseid != 'AllBlank'
GROUP BY
    h.dataareaid,
    h.warehouseid,
    h.itemno;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                        | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows  | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | h     | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 59644 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,itemno_category_class,itemstatus,itemstatuscolordescription,itemcolordescription,marketing,itemnodescription,itemnodescriptionupc,itemprices | PRIMARY | 32      | fiat.h.itemno              |     1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pe    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,itemno                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY | 20      | fiat.h.itemno              |     1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ph    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,date,itemno,itemno_2,date_2,eau_dollars                                                                                                      | PRIMARY | 50      | const,fiat.h.itemno        |     1 | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

New table #1:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT
    h.dataareaid,
    h.warehouse_id AS warehouseid,
    h.sku AS itemno,
    h.qty_onhand AS qoh,
    p.eau,
    p.fifo_cost,
    (h.qty_onhand * p.fifo_cost) AS value,
    ((p.cuft_inner / p.pcs_inner) * h.qty_onhand) AS cuft,
    p.status,
    CASE WHEN (p.status = 'P'
        OR p.isprivatelabel = 1
        OR p.sales_category_id = 7
        OR ph.smoothie_enabled != 1
        OR pe.firstsold > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        OR p.added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        GREATEST(h.qty_total_available - p.sold - p.allocated_qty - p.eau, 0)
    END AS excess_qty,
    CASE WHEN (p.status = 'P'
        OR p.isprivatelabel = 1
        OR p.sales_category_id = 7
        OR ph.smoothie_enabled != 1
        OR pe.firstsold > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        OR p.added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        GREATEST((h.qty_total_available - p.sold - p.allocated_qty - p.eau) * p.fifo_cost, 0)
    END AS excess_value
FROM
    lancia.warehouse_inventory AS h
    LEFT JOIN fiat.parts p ON p.itemno = h.sku
    LEFT JOIN fiat.parts_ext pe ON pe.itemno = h.sku
    LEFT JOIN internal.parts_history ph ON ph.itemno = h.sku AND ph.date = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE
    h.warehouse_id != 'AllBlank'
GROUP BY
    h.dataareaid, h.warehouse_id, h.sku;
    +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | h     | ALL  | NULL                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |  63068 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort           |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL  | NULL                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 115282 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pe    | ALL  | NULL                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 120843 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ph    | ref  | PRIMARY,date,date_2 | PRIMARY | 3       | const |      1 | Using where                                            |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Old table #1 schema:

```sql
mysql> desc fiat.parts_warehouse_items;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| itemno          | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| dataareaid      | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| warehouseid     | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| qoh             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_avail       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_posted      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_received    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_deducted    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_picked      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fifo_cost       | double(10,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| calculation     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| method          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_res_oh      | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| qty_avail_oh    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| qty_ordrd       | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| qty_res_ordrd   | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| qty_avail_ordrd | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| qty_on_order    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

New table #1 schema:

```sql
mysql> desc lancia.warehouse_inventory;
+---------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                   | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                        | int(11) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| sku                       | varchar(20)            | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| warehouse_id              | varchar(10)            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| site_id                   | varchar(10)            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| item_name                 | varchar(60)            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| item_color                | varchar(10)            | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| item_config               | varchar(50)            | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| item_size                 | varchar(10)            | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| item_style                | varchar(10)            | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| item_version              | varchar(10)            | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| item_status               | varchar(10)            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| qty_onhand                | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_onhand_reserved       | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_onhand_available      | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_ordered               | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_ordered_reserved      | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_ordered_available     | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_on_order              | decimal(32,6) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| qty_total_available       | decimal(32,6)          | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                |
| warehouse_management_used | tinyint(1) unsigned    | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| dataareaid                | varchar(4)             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at                | timestamp              | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+---------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: without seeing the tables and query we can't guess what is happening a EXPLAIN helps also

Comment: @nbk Posted the query and the explains, as well as primary table #1 (the one which varies) structure.  Do you need to see tables 2, 3 and 4 as well?  They're a bit lengthy.

Comment: In the future, please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not `DESCRIBE`.  The former is more descriptive; in particular, it would point out the charset and collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you join on equality, the two columns from the two tables in the ON clause should be of *precisely* the same data type, charset and collation included. Collations are baked into indexes.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I backed up my table, converted it to use the same character_set and collation sequence, and voila, proper joins and fast queries.  Thank you, O. Jones!